# Buttons not responding when full page url is not showed

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a website, let say the address is:
website.com
if i enter the website, and click a button that should pop a message box it will not work.

if i enter the website like this:
website.com/Default.aspx

which by the way both ways display the same page, but only when using the default.aspx name the buttons respond.

I tried doing this:

```
        if (!Request.Url.ToString().Contains("Default.aspx"))
        {
             Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
        }
```

but for some reason, did not help. Why is this happening and how do i fix it?

Buttonclick:

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Session.Clear();
        Session.RemoveAll();
        Response.Cookies.Clear();
        Login user = new Login(txtID.Text, txtPassword.Text);
        if (user.IsValid)
            whois = user.sc;
        else
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["hakerendbConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tblCEO WHERE id = '" + txtID.Text + "' AND password = '" + txtPassword.Text + "'", conn);
            conn.Open();
            if (cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString() == "1")
            {
                conn.Close();
                popupCeo.Visible = true;
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                conn.Close();
                ajaxPanel.Alert("ת.ז או סיסמא שגויה.");
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    catch { ajaxPanel.Alert("תקלה במערכת, אנא חזרו מאוחר יותר הבעיה בטיפול."); }
    try
    {
        HttpCookie user = new HttpCookie("UserName", Security.Encrypt(txtID.Text));
        user.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
        if (chkbox.Checked)
            user.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
        Response.Cookies.Clear();
        Response.Cookies.Add(user);
        switch (whois)
        {
            case Security.level.Investor:
                Response.Redirect("InvestorProjectViewer.aspx");
                break;
            case Security.level.Agent:
                Response.Redirect("AgentManager.aspx");
                break;
            case Security.level.SeniorAgent:
                Response.Redirect("SeniorManager.aspx");
                break;
        }
    }
    catch { }
}
```

Comment: Post the code of button click handler.

Answer (score 0):

If it's really hitting the same page, the cause will be some javascript that executes in the `OnClientClick` event handler of `btnLogin`.

Any javascript using `document.URL` would behave differently in your two scenarios, as the URL would end "default.aspx" in one case, but not in the other.

Comment: I dont have any OnClientClick Events. so what do i do?

Comment: Then perhaps your button click is in fact working. Have you tried setting a breakpoint?

Comment: I cant, the problem only occurs on the server for some reason.

Comment: Then setup [remote debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/233w9kd4.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

I solved this annoyance by creating a new Default.html page which basically all it does is redirect to the Default.aspx which is now called Login.aspx

Comment: This isn't a very good solution. You should find what your actual issue was and fix it. Probably a client side script error.